# jQuery $(window).scrollTop and Internet Explorer (11) not working

Tags: jquery

I cant seem to get this to trigger in IE11. Works fine in Chrome, FF and Safari

```
if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {

}
```

Comment: you can check to this link  
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831027/window-scroll-does-not-work-with-ie11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831027/window-scroll-does-not-work-with-ie11)!

Comment: This works for me in IE11: http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/2tgyfder/. What are you trying to accomplish exactly?